# Setup X-Frame Options in a virtual directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, lamp, x-frame-options

I have a LAMP site setup to translate the URL using mod rewrite from:

```
index.php?controller=items&method=show&id=4
```

to:

```
/items/show/4
```

I want to set `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` in the root directory (`/`), but unset it in a subdirectory (`/items`). This will prevent external websites from IFRAME'ing my website except specified directories. The problem is `/items` is not a directory where I can create an `.htaccess` file with the directive.

How can I unset `X-Frame-Options` in the `/items` directory?

Comment: I'm assuming that when you refer to the root directory, this header applies to any request in the root directory, not just the root directory itself? ie. `/` and `/foo` are both requests _in_ the root directory - to which this header should be applied.

Comment: This question belongs to serverfault (https://serverfault.com)

Comment: "I'm assuming that when you refer to the root directory, this header applies to any request in the root directory, not just the root directory itself?" 
No. By "root", I mean "/" only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *unset* the header for the "subdirectory" (unless this is being set by other means). You can literally just set it for requests to the root directory and nothing else.

Set an environment variable when the required URL-path is requested and set the `Header` conditionally based on whether the env var is set (using the `env=` argument of the `Header` directive).

For example, at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/[^/]*$" ROOT_DIRECTORY
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" env=ROOT_DIRECTORY
```

The regex `^/[^/]*$` only matches URLs that do not contain a slash (except at the start of the URL-path), so only matches requests for anything in the root directory, including the root directory itself.

The `SetEnvIf` then sets the env var `ROOT_DIRECTORY` (to the value `1`) if the requested URL matches the above regex. And the `Header` directive is only applied if this env var is set.

---

**UPDATE:**

> How do I set it to the root directory and everything else EXCEPT the "/items" subdirectory?

In that case you can do something like the following instead:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(?!items($|/))" SET_X_FRAME_OPTIONS
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" env=SET_X_FRAME_OPTIONS
```

This uses a *negative lookahead* (`(?!items($|/)`) in the regex to set the environment variable `SET_X_FRAME_OPTIONS` for all requests *except* for those to `/items` and `/items/<anything>`.

Again, the header is set conditionally based on whether this env var is set. There is nothing to "unset" for the specific URL-path, as it's not set for the URL-path to begin with.

Comment: "You can literally just set it for requests to the root directory and nothing else." But I have other "subdirectories" that want it to be set for like "/orders", and "/customers". How do I set it to the root directory and everything else EXCEPT the "/items" subdirectory?

Comment: @MichaelBernardo Ah OK. I've updated my answer to address that scenario.